# How do I initialize stim's tableau simulator to a random tableau?

Tags: stim

I want to create a `stim.TableauSimulator` with a random tableau as its state. I know I can get a random tableau using `stim.Tableau.random(num_qubits)`, but how do I do the same thing for the simulator?

Comment: *Note: copied for visibility from question at https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/issues/153*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`stim.TableauSimulator.set_inverse_tableau`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki/Stim-v1.7-Python-API-Reference#stim.TableauSimulator.set_inverse_tableau) to change the tableau simulator's state to a specific tableau, such as a random tableau from `stim.Tableau.random`.

For example:

```
import stim
random_tableau = stim.Tableau.random(10)
simulator = stim.TableauSimulator()
simulator.set_inverse_tableau(random_tableau**-1)

assert simulator.current_inverse_tableau() == random_tableau**-1
```

Computing the inverse using `**-1` isn't *technically* necessary here, since the distribution of inverses of random tableaus is the same as the distribution of random tableaus. But "how do I invert a tableau" is a natural followup question when learning about a method called `set_inverse_tableau`.